# What does the 'acting outrageously for the sake being outrageous' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I'm reading the book about the Simpsons, and don't understand what does the author want to say in this sentence.

'That episode, which had Rodney Dangerfield as the long lost son of Mr. Burns, also showcased the increasingly stupid and invincible nature of Homer. More than any previous year, Season 8 saw

> Homer acting outrageously for the sake of being outrageous.

The third act of “Burns, Baby Burns” is Homer’s cartoonish efforts to stage a “phony kidnapping”, the purpose of which is to get Mr. Burns to admit he loves his son. It was the kind of frenetic scheme that sitcom characters have been doing since the days of I Love Lucy, but it wasn’t something Homer had done before.'

I suppose the author wants to say that Homer acting like not himself or maybe acting too far-fetched, but I'm not sure. What do you think?

Comment: have you researched: for the sake of? That's your clue.

Comment: I understand what it means. But I don't understand the definition 'outrageous' in the context of that sentence. I just want to hear any versions from other people. I mean, I made an assumption, but I'm not sure that I'm right.

Comment: Right. Have you looked up outrageous? Try: outrageous behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It basically just means that Homer is crazy and doesn't think things through. It's like teenagers being crazy for the sake of being crazy and loud. Yeah, they're having fun doing it, but they aren't thinking about the consequences

Comment: It means he is acting crazy **just to*** act crazy. That is the key point of ***for the sake of***. :)